# Error in event of onSubmit when validate the empty text box

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am implementing a form in html and check empty text boxes on `onSubmit` event of form. In my JavaScript code I returns false but the form is still submit and redirect to new URL.
What goes wrong in this code?

```
function checkBlank(form)
{
    var returnvar=true;
    if(form.driver.value=="")
    {
        alert("You can't left  text box Driver as blank.. ");
        driver.focus();
        returnvar=false;
    }       
    return returnvar
}


 <form name="form1" action="/Assignment6/DataBaseServlet"  onSubmit="return checkBlank(form1);" method="post">
```

Answer (score 2):

You changed your variable names

```
returnvar
returnval
```

and the onsubmit line

```
return checkBlank(form1);
```

should use `this` and not `form1`

```
return checkBlank(this);
```

Also `driver` is not defined.

```
driver.focus();
```

It should be referenced with the `form`

```
form.driver.focus();
```

Comment: There is no such kind of variable returnval.itis typing mistake. it is returnvar.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire function can be:

```
function checkBlank(form) {
  return form.driver.value == "";
}
```

If you the message isn't required. Or perhaps:

```
function checkBlank(form) {
  if (!form.driver.value) {
    alert("Please enter a value in the driver field");
    return false;
  }
}
```

But you may want slightly more robust validation as that will allow a string of one or more spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Hi its because of action tag .
I just change my code lke this and it's working fine.`enter code here`

```
 function checkBlank(form)
  {
var returnval=true;
form.action="/Assignment_8/";
if(form.driver.value=="")
    {
    alert("You can't left  text box Driver as blank ");

    driver.focus();     
    returnval= false;
    }
if(form.url.value=="")
{
alert("You can't left  text box url as blank ");
form.url.focus();
returnval= false;
}
if(form.username.value=="")
{
alert("You can't left  text box username as blank ");
form.username.focus();
returnval= false;
}
if(form.password.value=="")
{
alert("You can't left  text box password as blank ");
form.password.focus();
returnval= false;
}
if(form.query.value=="")
{
alert("You can't left  text box query as blank ");
form.query.focus();
returnval= false;
}
if(returnval){
    form.action="/Assignment_8/database.jsp";
   }
    return true;
}
 //and form tag is..
   <form name=form1  method="post" onsubmit="return checkBlank(form1)">
```